# Associar ApplicationUser do Identity à minha classe PessoaFisica

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Meu sistema Asp.Net MVC usa o Identity na sua forma default, com algumas personalizações simples. Também possuo uma tabela de Pessoas Físicas (que herda algumas informações de Pessoas, mas acho que isso não vem ao caso).

Gostaria de associar o ApplicationUser à PessoaFisica, de forma que todo ApplicationUser tenha uma PessoaFisica (PessoaFisica podem ter ou não um ApplicationUser).

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   [ForeignKey("PessoaFisica")]
   public int PessoaFisicaId { get; set; }

   public virtual PessoaFisica PessoaFisica { get; set; }

   public async Task GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager manager)
   {
      ...
    }
}
```

Na classe PessoaFisica tenho o seguinte:

```
[Table("Pessoas")]
public partial class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Nome { get; set; }

   ...

   public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

O erro que obtenho é:

*One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:*

ApplicationUser_Pessoa_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'ApplicationUser_PessoaFisica_Source' in relationship 'ApplicationUser_PessoaFisica'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Colocando o relacionamento com fluent API na model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity‹PessoaFisica›()
   .HasOptional(f => f.Usuario)
   .WithRequired(s => s.PessoaFisica);
}
```

Também tenho um erro, mas é outro:

*Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'WebApplication5.Models.PessoaFisica' and 'WebApplication5.Models.ApplicationUser'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.*

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O seu problema aí é que várias pessoas físicas podem se referir ao mesmo ApplicationUser.

Answer (score -1):

Achei muito complicado implementar isso. Muitos erros relacionados ao Identity.

Acabei fazendo um relacionamento meio a forma, consultando minha tabela cada vez que quero consultar o usuário de uma pessoa física. O mesmo faço para consultar a pessoa física de um usuário. Espero que ajude alguém.

Classe ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public int PessoaFisicaId { get; set; }
   public virtual PessoaFisica PessoaFisica
   {
      get
      {
         MinhaModel db = new MinhaModel();
         var pessoaFisica = db.PessoasFisicas.Find(PessoaFisicaId);
         return pessoaFisica;
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Classe PessoaFisica:

```
public class PessoaFisica : Pessoa
{
   public string Cpf { get; set; }
   public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario
   {
      get
      {
         ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
         var usuario = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.PessoaFisicaId == Id);
         return usuario;
      }
   }
}
```

Uso em um Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
   PessoaFisica pessoaFisica = db.PessoasFisicas.Find(id);
   var nomeUsuario = pessoaFisica.Usuario.UserName;
   return View(pessoaFisica);
}
```

Uso em um View:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using NomeAplicacao.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
@{
    var manager = new UserManager(new UserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var usuario = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
}
…
@Html.ActionLink("Olá " + usuario.PessoaFisica.Nome + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
…
```